# Primary Constructor Feature C#12 doesn't compile

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I am trying to use the new C#12 Primary Constructor feature in a Console App but i doesn't work.

```
   public class Foo(int x, int y)
   {
        public int Z => x + y;
   }


   internal class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var x = new Foo(0,1);
       }
   }
```

[image]

The Error is:

> Class cannot have a primary constructor

My csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I am using Visual Studio Version 17.8.0 and have the sdk installed. The Language Version is C#12.

```
8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Using a struct doesn't work either.
Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qkULG9

Comment: Code builds for me locally, too...

Comment: It's worth running `dotnet --version` to check you're using the SDK you think you are - if you have a global.json somewhere in the directory hierarchy, that could be pinning it to an earlier one.

Comment: Type `#error version`, it will tell you the language version.

Comment: If it was because the wrong compiler version was used, would it even know what a primary constructor is?

Comment: Have you tried building it from console with `dotnet build`?

Comment: I deleted the obj and bin folders and restarted Visual Studio. The Error is gone now. I am still not sure why. I was building using Visual Studio. Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: I had this problem and resolved it by updating JetBrains.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko fiddle reproduces the issue in Visual Studio indeed https://imgur.com/a/4pyYmmf.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as not reproducible. I had this issue, found this question, @pdpc provided the correct answer (had outdated ReSharper). Solid stack overflow loop to me :)

Comment: Re-installation of VisualStudio made the problem go away for me

Comment: For me it was also resharper but for whatever reason VS was saying I had the latest version when in fact it wasn't... Had to manually download latest version and install it